# Error: "Sorry you are not allowed to upload this file type" when uploading image to wordpress via API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, api, vuejs3

I'm making an app for my clients to create and edit content on their wordpress site. I'm stuck on a problem when trying to upload images.

I'm using vue 3 and ionic as my framework and currently testing on an android phone. Im sending a POST request with this fetch:

```
const uploadPhotos = async () => {
        cameraStatus.value = 'uploading started'
        await store.create();

        const photoList = await store.get('photos');
        const photosInStorage = photoList ? JSON.parse(photoList) : [];
        const files = await photosInStorage.map((photo: any) => {
            return Filesystem.readFile({
                path: photo.filepath,
            })
        })
        const filesUploaded = await Promise.all(files)
        cameraStatus.value = 'gotten images'
        console.log(filesUploaded)
        for(let i = 0; i < filesUploaded.length; i++) {
            const file = filesUploaded[i];
            cameraStatus.value = 'uploading' + file
            const requestOptions = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "file/jpeg",
                    "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg',
                    'Authorization': 'basic ' + Buffer.from(wpUsername + ":" + wpApplicationPassword).toString('base64')
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    file: file.data
                })
            }
            await fetch(wpSite + '/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
                requestOptions
            )
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    cameraStatus.value = data;
                }).catch(error => {
                    cameraStatus.value = error;
                })
        }
    }
```

.
It works when uploading it as .txt put not as .jpg, .jpeg or .png. It returns the error: "Sorry you are not allowed to upload this file type" when i try to upload any of the image types.

I have tried disabling all plugins and themes but with no luck.

I tried contacting the hosting provider and they said it is on my end.

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Comment: Should'nt `Content-Type` be `image/jpg`?

Comment: @cabrerahector No still gives same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:

[Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

I used the b64toBlob function on the file.data instead of stringify and it worked.